# Specified cast is not Valid (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, enums

In my main form code, I've added this:

```
public static ShoeStyle selectedStyle;
```

`ShoeStyle` is the name of an enum I have in a class. I want `selectedStyle` to contain the name of whatever I select in my combo box. Like this

```
private void cmbShoeList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedStyle = (ShoeStyle)cmbShoeList.SelectedValue;                       
}
```

But when I run the program, it gives me the error:

> specified cast is not valid.

I'm not sure how I can fix this. I've heard of the term cast before but am unfamiliar with it

Comment: Try following : (ShoeStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(ShoeStyle), cmbShoeList.SelectedValue)

Comment: The `(ShoeStyle)` is the cast. A cast is when you try to take something of one type and make it another type. In this case, you likely have a string type (`SelectedValue`) and you are trying to cast it as the `ShoeStyle` type. There's nothing telling the compiler how to do that, so that's why you get the error.

Comment: @jdweng awesome, your code worked. Thanks